# How to conflate feminine and masculine last names for a couple?

Tags: род

I am writing an English letter to a married Russian couple, and they've got the same root for their last name, with a '-a' suffix for hers. Is there an acceptable way to address them both without writing out both names in full?

For example, for a couple 'Eva Ivanova' and 'Victor Ivanov', could I address them collectively as 'Eva and Victor Ivanov[a]'?

Comment: @VitalyOsipov Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just the same way like in English you can put any last name in the plural to mean "the family of ...", like `the Smiths, the Lennons, the Bushes`, so you can do that in Russian, and that's what you need to do when addressing a couple. In your case, you can write `Ева и Виктор Ивановы`. Still, putting last names into plural and declining them is a tricky thing when dealing with Russian, Rosental has a [whole chapter](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_06) devoted to that. What is the most important, is that last names (rather rare ones, though) that end in `-аго, -ако, -яго, -ых, -их, -ово` and (Ukrainian, rather widespread) that end in `-ко (-енко)` are not declined, and their plural is the same as the singular, that is why `Ева Черных` and `Ева и Виктор Черных`, `Виктор Петренко` and `Ева и Виктор Петренко`.

Comment: The question was how to write it in English, so the answer is useless.

Comment: @user31264 - If the question is about English, then why is it asked at the site about Russian? Here I answer only about Russian words, their forms, and sentences made up of those words.

Answer (score 4):

Using first name + patronimic for each of them is the normal polite way to address a Russian couple, whether you're writing in English or in Russian.

For example, "Dear Olga Petrovna & Viktor Vladimirovich".

Your own example sounds very official, government-like.